# RHEL7.2 Linux Multipathing

Tags: linux, rhel7

I am try to setup multipath for one of the RHEL7.1 server and the storage backend is Hitachi.

So can anyone give me  the settings for hitachi for active/active?  I want to verify this but this below looks like active/failover.

```
[root@kilocompute01 ~]# multipath -ll

mpathe (360060e80100b07b00530288300000017) dm-8 HITACHI ,DF600F size=500G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
|-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=1 status=active
| |- 2:0:0:4  sdv  65:80  active ready running
| `- 0:0:0:4  sdf  8:80   active ready running
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=0 status=enabled
  |- 2:0:1:4  sdad 65:208 active ready running
  `- 0:0:1:4  sdn  8:208  active ready running ---Snip
```

Thanks,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as required for Stackoverflow. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The question *may* be appropriate on other SE sites such as [unix.se].

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

DF600F refers to several generations of midrange Hitachi arrays like AMS1xxx, AMS2xxx, HUS. They are typically active/active-asymmetric arrays or ALUA arrays. So they have active/active frontend ports. Nevertheless, for better performance it's recommended to set active paths though LUN-owner controllers. See Hitachi Dynamic Link Manager (HDLM) software for better multipathing administration of Hitachi arrays.